# Node.js module.exports function return array from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My module contains

```
module.exports.findByUser = function(username, callback){
    var test = db.collection("somecollection");
    test.find({Username: username}, callback);
}
```

And my route is configured as follows:

```
router.get('/page', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.user.username;
    somemodule.findByUser(username, function(err, resp){
        console.log(resp.toArray());
    });
    res.render('page', {title: 'test page'})
});
```

Console.log outputs Promise .

My issue is: how do I get the findByUser function to return the array of results from the query?
Maybe this isn't even the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#toArray) method on the cursor to return an array of results as follows:

```
module.exports.findByUser = function(username, callback){
    var test = db.collection("somecollection");
    test.find({Username: username}).toArray(callback);
}
```

which can be called as

```
router.get('/page', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.user.username;
    somemodule.findByUser(username, function(err, resp){
        console.log(resp);
        res.render('page', {
            title: 'test page',
            data: resp
        });
    });   
});
```

---

Using async/await you can do the above as:

```
module.exports.findByUser = function(username){
    const test = db.collection("somecollection");
    return test.find({Username: username}).toArray(); // return promise
}
```

Called as

```
router.get('/page', ensureAuthenticated, async function(req, res, next) {
    const resp = await somemodule.findByUser(req.user.username);
    console.log(resp);
    res.render('page', {
        title: 'test page',
        data: resp
    });
})
```

or just using the promise

```
router.get('/page', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    somemodule.findByUser(req.user.username).then(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        res.render('page', {
            title: 'test page',
            data: resp
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    })
})
```